# Marxism had abolished philosophy. What did Engels mean?

Tags: marxism

I read somewhere that Engels has  asserted that Marxism had abolished philosophy. What did he mean?

Comment: An exact quote, with context would help.  Also there is a philosophy stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Marx and Engels were rather dismissive of philosophy in the Hegelian mould. Marx is [quoted](https://www.lrb.co.uk/v09/n16/alan-ryan/can-marxism-be-rescued) as saying "Philosophy stands to the study of the real world in the same relationship as masturbation stands to real sexual love." This points to the idea that Engels is trying to communicate: Marxism is not an abstract idea to be discussed and debated, it is an active movement leading to revolution and the overthrow of bourgeois society.

Marxism has abolished philosophy as there is no place in the communist utopia for abstract philosophy. Or put more bluntly "Don't think; Do!"

Whether there is any merit to this position is beyond the scope of this answer.